# How to block in some Win file(s) all websites except the ones from my list?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I run Windows 7 Home Premium. I know that the Windows HOSTS file doesn't support wildcard entries so I can't use a syntax like:

```
127.0.0.1 *
123.456.789.012 allowed-domain1.com
111.222.333.444 allowed-domain2.com
...
```

But I need to reach the goal without installing any additional software and only with changes in some Win file(s) in order to hide the file(s) in the further.

Is it possible and how to?

Comment: the HOSTS file is not, and never will be a method for blocking access to websites. But, if you plan to do something as rudimentary as this then just remove the DNS servers on the network adapter and you will accomplish the same thing as `127.0.0.1 *`.

Comment: I don't know exactly where I should find the DNS server on my PC. And what if there is no one? Or is it always on every PC?

Comment: Your DNS server is either set to be your ISP, your network device your pc is connected to, or some other third-party DNS provider.  There are a few third-party DNS providers that provide the ability to block or filter content.

Comment: Can I "remove" DNS server by editing certain Win file(s) and without possibility to restore it again unless Windows re-installation?

Comment: And what if I remove `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DNSRegisteredAdapters` ?